# when my iphone receiving calls, and my app is in background, i want call some codes (alert coreblue4.0 device)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background, bluetooth

I have used ctcallcenter, and use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, so I have only 10 minutes to call my codes. How can I make it longer，the app proxBLE have achieved it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3), you can extend the execution time only in the below cases. In order to do that, you need to add the `UIBackgroundModes` key to `info.plist` file. See the detailed explanation below.

### Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks

For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their
  location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support
  Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to
  download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates
  from external accessories

***Apps that implement these services must declare the services they support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your application from being suspended.***

---

### Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks

Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by the app that uses them. An app declares support for a service using its `Info.plist` file. Add the `UIBackgroundModes` key to your `Info.plist` file and set its value to an array containing one or more of the following strings:

- `audio`—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content using AirPlay.)
- `location`—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
- `voip`—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
- `newsstand-content`—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
- `external-accessory`—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External Accessory framework.
- `bluetooth-central`—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the Core Bluetooth framework.
- `bluetooth-peripheral`—The app supports Bluetooth communication in peripheral mode through the Core Bluetooth framework.

Each of the preceding values lets the system know that your app should be woken up at appropriate times to respond to relevant events. For example, an app that begins playing music and then moves to the background still needs execution time to fill the audio output buffers. Including the `audio` key tells the system frameworks that they should continue playing and make the necessary callbacks to the app at appropriate intervals. If the app does not include this key, any audio being played by the app stops when the app moves to the background.